# inputing choices for a flask poll app

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I have made a database schema for a poll app I am making using Flask as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
    question_id integer primary key autoincrement,
    questiontext string not null
);

CREATE TABLE choices (
    choice_id integer primary key autoincrement,
    choicetext string not null,
    question_id integer,
    FOREIGN KEY(question_id) REFERENCES questions(question_id)
);
```

But I couldn't figure out how I should ask(in the HTML template) and insert the choices into the database. My 'show_polls' and 'add_polls' are below

```
    @app.route('/')
def show_polls():
    cur = g.db.execute('SELECT questiontext, choicetext FROM questions q JOIN choices c ON c.question_id = q.question_id') 
    polls = [dict(question=row[0], choices=(c for c in row[1:])) for row in cur.fetchall()] 
    return render_template('show_polls.html', polls=polls)

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_poll():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    g.db.execute('insert into questions (questiontext) values (?)', 
            [request.form['questiontext']])

    for i in range(4): #4 choices
        g.db.execute('insert into choices (choicetext, question_id) values(?, ?)',
                [request.form['choicetext'], 4])
    g.db.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('show_polls'))
```

But this doesn't work. I'm not sure whether I've got the views wrong or the HTML layout part. Can anyone help me with this please?

Here's the HTML part that adds the polls:

```
{% for i in range(4) %}
            <dt>Choices:
            <dd><input type=text name=choicetext>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without the full template or HTML, I am going to assume the HTML `<form>` is valid.  See [HTML Forms and Inputs](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) if you suspect a problem there.

To verify that form values are reaching your add_poll() function, try using [Flask debug mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#debug-mode) (i.e. set `app.debug = True` prior to `app.run()`).  To force invocation of the debugger, insert an error in the add_poll() function and submit the form again from a browser.  A copy of the Traceback should appear.  Click on the 'console' icon in the last line of the traceback (which should be the error you created inside add_poll()) and start interactively inspecting the request.form object.

```
[console ready]
>>> request.form
werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict({'choicetext': u''})
>>> str(request.form)
"ImmutableMultiDict([('choicetext', u'choice1'), ('choicetext', u'choice2'), ('choicetext', u'choice3'), ('choicetext', u'choice4')])"
>>> dir(request.form)
['KeyError', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__copy__', '__delattr__',    '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'add', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'getlist', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'iterlists', 'iterlistvalues', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'lists', 'listvalues', 'pop', 'popitem', 'popitemlist', 'poplist', 'setdefault',         'setlist', 'setlistdefault', 'to_dict', 'update', 'values'  ]
>>> request.form.getlist('choicetext')
[u'choice1', u'choice2', u'choice3', u'choice4']
```

Hopefully this will make clear what must change in add_poll() and simplify future debug of your app.  Good luck!

For more information, read the documentation on [Flask.request.form](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.request.form) and [werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict) objects.  For an example of handling form validation within Flask (the next step after the plumbing is in place), this [Flask pattern document on Form Validation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/wtforms/) might be a good place to start.